# one txt file used by many users in the server

Tags: php, multithreading, text, server

I have a .txt file in a server which will be used for writing enormous data and then reading the data each time the user login in the system .

my question is this:

The total number of users which will be using the system is around 5000 on their suitable time.
I am just worried about closing ,opening , reading and writing to the same file and 
for multiple users on the same time. can you advice if it is safe and it will work.

Comment: Why don't simply use a DBMS?

Comment: Define safe. Define work. Also, what @DavidePastore - why not use a database? They're designed for concurrency in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are worried about is called a race condition.
Concurrency control is what controls concurrent access to a resource.

The easiest way to avoid race conditions is to use mutex locks. This way only one person at a time can access it. Note that you cannot write your own lock systems since it still has a race condition. A mutex must be part of the language.
The problem with a lock is that the other person has to wait for access.

The best way is to just use a database as suggested and let that handle the concurrency.

Comment: `Note that you cannot write your own lock systems since it still has a race condition` - what? Actually you can control concurrent access to a file using PHP. But it's really not desirable. Your answer makes it sound as if it's not possible, when in reality - it is.

Comment: From what I can recall you need atomic operations to be able to lock something for mutual exclusion and that while trying to write it yourself you are still prone to race conditions. But I could be dead wrong.

Comment: PHP works with concurrent environment in mind, and it can acquire an exclusive lock while working with a file. Since I can't really tell to what race condition you might be prone, I can't say with certainty whether you have the right or wrong thing in mind. However, in this example - where you have 1 write at any one time, you can acquire an exclusive lock. But the important thing is use of database which you suggested, which is why I'll +1 this answer.